# deploy bitnami django

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, bitnami

I am quite computer-illiterate, but I have managed to utilize the Django framework on my own machine. I have had an account on Amazon Web Service (AWS) for some time, but it appeared rather complex to set-up and to make use of, so I put it of for a while. Then I decided to give it a try, and it was not so hard as I first thought to load a AMI and connect to the server with PuTTY. But since I were already using BitNami's Django-Stack, I decided to take a look at their hosting offer (which builds on AWS). Since they appeared to offer "one-click deployment", I set up a new server through their interface. But then, it seems like the "one-click deployment"-promise is with regard to the server itself. There does not seem to be any interface for deploying Django projects through their site. Having used PuTTY already, and adding WinSCP to my machine, I can acceess the server and load my Django-code unto the server. But then I am lost. The documentation seems a bit thin (look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/)).

The crux of this is the following: Can anyone make this part of the process more understandable. I.e., how to deploy a Django project on a Linux server with Apache/mod_WSGI?

The other question is: I want to use Postgres. Am I free to install this on the server. Should I opt for EBM (EMB?) for this, or what is the downside of not having EBM?

I hope I am not too unworthy of your attention, thanks!

Comment: I am also fairly new and share your same problem. This might be dodging your question but it also might serve as a good "plan b" for you. Heroku is another PaaS based host and allows integration of Django and Postgres. Maybe it's not necessarily any easier than BitNami, but at least there is an excellent tutorial for taking a Django project and getting it on the web: http://gettingstartedwithdjango.com/en/lessons/introduction-and-launch/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`how to deploy a Django project on a Linux server with Apache/mod_WSGI`  The Bitnami AMI already comes with all this configured. Once installed try going to the `EC2 public url` on the default `8000` port and you  will see the demo django project setup there. You can add your own project once you have logged into the machine via putty check the `/home/bitnami/` directory for the demo project. Copy your project, configure your database   `The other question is: I want to use Postgres. Am I free to install this on the server`  `Postgres` and `Mysql` are already installed the same way you would do on your local machine. The in your project do `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9000` since the `8000` port is already running another application.